# Dynamically create and run bash script sections concurrently

Tags: bash

I am experienced in Bash and I have set of variables stored in a array which I want to pass in a shell script that I want to run simultaneously
Right now I have something like this dummy code working

```
array = (1 2 3 4)

for i in array
do
 if [condition] then;
    call script1
 else 
    call script2
 fi
done
```

But what I want is instead of going through the elements of the array one by one, I want to run concurrently everything in the loop for each of them . How would I do that. I know how to call scripts concurrently using & but I am not sure how to handle the if conditions.

Comment: I seen people abusing xargs for this.

Comment: Need some inputs on what you mean by 'everything in the loop for each of them'

Comment: Instead of iterating through the array for each element, running all the elements concurrently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)? I think it's exactly what you're looking for. I'm no expert with parallel, but I know you can easily pipe a list of newline separated commands into it:

```
# An array of commands to run in parallel
array=(command1 command2 command3 command4)

# Pipe the array of commands to parallel as a list
(IFS=$'\n'; echo "${array[*]}") | parallel -j4
```

The `-j` flag lets you selects how many parallel threads to run. Parallel will go through the list, executing each line in parallel with `bash -c` until all lines have been executed.

I often use a for loop to build a list of commands and pipe the output directly into parallel. For example:

```
## Multicore Parallel FizzBuzz Engine
for((i=1;i<=100;++i));do
  echo 'i='$i';p="";((i%3==0))&&p=Fizz;((i%5==0))&&p+=Buzz;[[ ! $p ]]&&p=$i;echo $p;'; 
done | parallel -kj4
```